# Need guidance on setting up variables and arrays properly in my assembly source code file

Tags: assembly, codewarrior, 68hc12

I'm told that there is "Absolute Assembly" and "Relocatable Assembler" choices when setting up my assembly code project in CodeWarrior. I'm not using the HCS12 microcontroller at the moment as I am just trying to get my code to assemble and step through correctly. I have chosen "Relocatable" because I believe it makes my code more readable and breaks it down into sections. However, I am having a hard time understanding how I need to set up variables and arrays properly.

I know that a variable has an address in RAM. Therefore I would think I would need to define this address. I'm also told that I need to define how big the variable is in other words if it is 1-byte or 2-bytes and so on.

I'm thinking the same applies to arrays. So I need to define location and size. I also need to fill up my array with values.

When I assemble the below code it tells me that there is no memory at the location I set for R1 and R2. I don't follow because I did up at the beginning of my programming using the EQU directive.

I don't understand when I'm suppose to use DC. or DS. and how that is different from using the EQU. It seems all the same and now i'm just confused in general on how to set up variables and arrays.

```
    ;************************PROGRAM HEADER******************
;   PROJECT NAME:
;   FILE NAME:
;   DEVELOPER:      
;   DATE CREATED:
;   PROGRAM PURPOSE:
;   REVISIONS:
;********************************************************


;************************GLOBAL SYMBOLS******************
;   External Symbol Definitions
;   Internal Symbol Definitions
              XDEF      Entry, main
;********************************************************


;************************EQUATES (EQU)*******************
R1            EQU           $1000
R2            EQU           $1100
;********************************************************


;************************CODE SECTION********************
;   Section Start
MyCode:     SECTION
Entry:
main:
;   Initialize Stack Pointer
                LDS         #$2000
;   Initialize all I/O Devices
;   Initialize Variable Data
                    CLRA
                    CLRB
                LDAA        #4
                STAA        R1
                STAB        R2
                LDX         #List1
;   Start of Main Code
back                LDAA        R2        ;This is suppose to add up each
                ADDB        0, X      ;element in my array "List1". If
                INX                           ;there is a carry it branches out
                BCS         CARRY     ;to the carry loop, performs the 
                LDAA                R1        ;carry operation and returns to
                DECA                          ;original start of first loop. My
                STAA                R1        ;variable R1 is the counter which
                BNE         back      ;is the size of my array "List1".

CARRY                   INCA
                STAA        R2
                LDAA        R1
                DECA
                STAA        R1
                BNE         back

                LDAA        R2
;************************END OF CODE*********************


;************************SUBROUTINES & FUNCTIONS*********
;********************************************************


;************************CONSTANT DATA SECTION (ROM)*****
;   Section Start
;   Data Definitions
;********************************************************


;************************VARIABLE DATA SECTION (RAM)*****
;   Section Start
MyData:     SECTION
;   Variable Data Storage Allocation
List1:      DC.B     $FF, $01, $FE, $02
;********************************************************
```

Comment: I apologize for the code being scrambled. I cannot figure out how to properly insert code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not famailiar with the assembler you are using, but EQU simply assigns a value to a symbol. In your assembler, `DC` or `DS` would appear to define storage, where the label is defined as the start of the storage area.

`DC.B` would appear to assign bytes, so if you want R1 to be defined as a memory location containing the value $1000 I'd anticipate that

```
R1:  DC.W $1000
R2:  DC.W $1100
```

entered after `List1:` should logically reserve a WORD or storage containing the values nominated.
Naturally, yo'd need to delete your `EQU` definition, else the assembler will object to the double-definition.